# How to use Node.Js in place of MySQL

Tags: mysql, node-js

I want to know if it's possible to use Node.js in place of MySQL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.


Comment: Not so sure this in regards to programming since [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) has a built-in HTTP server.

Comment: Unfortunately it is also too broad for this site.

Comment: Out of scope does seem more accurate.

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to use a sofa in place of my car?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. Node.js and MySQL are completely different things.

From http://nodejs.org:

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

From http://mysql.com:

> The world's most popular open source database

As you can see, one is a database (MySQL), the other one isn't.

You can however use [MySQL and Node.js together](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mysql), or you can use a plethora of other database systems in combination with Node.

Answer (score 0):

No and yes.

No because Node.js is just a javascript library not a DB.

Yes because there's something being cooked right now called tingodb which is a DB and capable of replacing MySQL.

http://www.tingodb.com/